# custom pipelines in RASA : getting pipeline output

Tags: nlp, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

Suppose I make a pipeline that only extracts entities, then how do I get these output entities ??
for example, this is my pipeline :

```
pipeline:
- name: "SpacyNLP"
- name: "CRFEntityExtractor"
- name: "EntitySynonymMapper"
```

how do I get the output entities?

Answer (score 0):

You can train an nlu-only model, then if you run `rasa shell nlu` with an entities-only pipeline you will see the entities predicted e.g.

```
{
  "intent": {
    "name": null,
    "confidence": 0.0
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "start": 7,
      "end": 11,
      "value": "apples",
      "entity": "food",
      "confidence": 0.9887154577118213,
      "extractor": "CRFEntityExtractor"
    }
  ],
  "text": "i like apples"
}
```

You could also load the model in python and use `interpreter.parse()` to get results, or run `rasa run --enable-api` and hit the `/model/parse` endpoint.

Incidentally, the pipeline posted won't work - you need to provide a tokenizer before `CRFEntityExtractor` e.g.

```
language: en
pipeline: 
  - name: "WhitespaceTokenizer"
  - name: "CRFEntityExtractor"
  - name: "EntitySynonymMapper"
```